# How to use the mouse wheel to slide the QML page based on ScrollBar?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to create a child window to show an article that can't be fully displayed by the *window*. For now, I can slide the page through dragging the *ScrollBar* (QML Type), but I want to slide it by using the mouse wheel as well.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id:privacyWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title:qsTr("Privacy")

    Rectangle {
        id: privacy
        clip: true
        width: privacyWindow.width
        height: privacyWindow.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: textArea
            clip: true
            width: privacyWindow.width - 150
            height: privacyWindow.height
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            Text {
                id: content
                width: textArea.width
                text: ""
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                textFormat: Text.RichText
                //x: -horizontalBar.position * width
                y: -verticalBar.position * height
            }
        }

        ScrollBar {
            id: verticalBar
            hoverEnabled: true
            active: hovered || pressed
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            size: privacy.height / content.height
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you. :)

Comment: You can try to use a mouse area in your window, or rectangle https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-wheelevent.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have managed to solve it by replacing Rectangle with Flickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by replacing *Rectangle* with *Flickable*.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: privacyWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title:qsTr("Privacy")

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        clip: true
        width: privacyWindow.width - 150
        height: privacyWindow.height
        contentWidth: content.width
        contentHeight:content.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Text {
            id: content
            width: flickable.width
            text: ""
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            parent: flickable.parent
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```